# javascript was blocked due to MIME type mismatch Domino 10.0.4

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

[image: **enter image description here**]

After upgrading our domino server to V10.0.4 the traditional web application fails to load the scripts on page with error MIME type (text/HTML) is not executable.. Is there any notes.ini I need to include or change any server configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the JS files are stored in the Resources - Files section of the nsf.

Try setting the MIME type manually on each file by adding "application/javascript" as Mime Type on the Web Properties tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Per, it did the trick .... I have changed the content type to other in page properties as text/javascript , the javascrips are written on the pages with extension.js ,but the question is it runs without any changes on Domino 9.0.1FP8 but not on 10.0.1FP4 may be I will connect HCL support

Comment: HCL will have tightened up on mime-type declarations to improve security and to be compliant with modern web standards. General/loose mime-types are not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `NOTES.INI` setting on your servers

```
HTTP_DISABLE_X_CONTENT_TYPE_OPTIONS_NOSNIFF=1
```

That came from HCL support March 2021.

Comment: Please consider adding a link to the new documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Also try:
**HTTPAdditionalRespHeader01=X-Content-Type-Options: sniff**
Was having Javascript errors after upgrading from Domino R9.0.1FP8 to R11.0.1FP3
I applied this setting, restarted the HTTP task and everything worked again.
Browser in use was IE11
https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0077199&sys_kb_id=731074a71b6f8414c48197d58d4bcb2c